# Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly very slow to load the Desktop [about 30s]

Tags: boot, gnome, login, desktop-environments

I'm experiencing a long time between login and having access to my desktop. Almost 32s in this black screen showing only the cursor.
I don't know how to provide the proper information and the terminal commands to have it. I switched to Linux last October. After the desktop loads, gnome runs fine.

systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 3.519s (firmware) + 4.755s (loader) + 2.187s (kernel) + 11.556s (userspace) = 22.018s 
graphical.target reached after 11.336s in userspace
```

systemd-analyze blame

```
6.573s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
6.373s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
3.507s dev-nvme0n1p2.device                                                                     
2.246s snapd.service                                                                            
 973ms snap-libreoffice-208.mount                                                               
 960ms snap-simplenote-524.mount                                                                
 926ms snap-thunderbird-119.mount                                                               
 874ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount                                                  
 831ms snap-libreoffice-213.mount                                                               
 821ms snap-thunderbird-122.mount                                                               
 785ms snap-simplenote-544.mount                                                                
 760ms dev-loop3.device                                                                         
 758ms snap-pdfmixtool-822.mount                                                                
 752ms snap-snapd-11402.mount                                                                   
 695ms snap-zoom\x2dclient-143.mount                                                            
 667ms snap-snapd-11588.mount                                                                   
 591ms snap-bpytop-229.mount                                                                    
 586ms dev-loop4.device                                                                         
 573ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                                                  
 572ms dev-loop5.device                                                                         
 571ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                                                  
 569ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d14\x2dcore18-4.mount                           
 568ms dev-loop6.device                                                                         
 565ms snap-pdfmixtool-857.mount                                                                
 548ms dev-loop7.device                                                                         
 530ms snap-zoom\x2dclient-142.mount                                                            
 523ms dev-loop8.device                                                                         
 516ms dev-loop11.device                                                                        
 511ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b3c43f65\x2d0ad4\x2d4449\x2dbc54\x2d5ebc4e823c68.service
lines 1-29
```

systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @11.336s
└─multi-user.target @11.336s
  └─kerneloops.service @11.109s +19ms
    └─network-online.target @11.107s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.733s +6.373s
        └─NetworkManager.service @4.615s +116ms
          └─dbus.service @4.612s
            └─basic.target @4.604s
              └─sockets.target @4.604s
                └─snapd.socket @4.604s +599us
                  └─sysinit.target @4.599s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @4.516s +82ms
                      └─apparmor.service @4.422s +93ms
                        └─local-fs.target @4.422s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @6.36>
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @5.565s
                              └─swap.target @3.875s
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-cbc8f1e5\x2d2e00\x2d4a8a\>
                                  └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-cbc8f1e5\x2d2e00\x2d4a8>
lines 1-22/22 (END)
```

Comment: Welcome, you need to add the output of `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: Hi @GAD3R ! Thank you in advance for the commands. I added the outputs in my post.

Comment: I tried to disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service and remove all the Snaps. In theory the time has been reduced, but i'm still getting this 30s of Black Screen after login. Could it be something related to the Nvidia drivers?